# Memory leak with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a program which will read 1 million records from the database and insert the records into another table after some processing. So, the program calls a DAO API to get 1 million records and loop through them in memory. The insertion is also using a DAO API to do the insert. Each DAO API part is implemented as

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TableA> tableAs = GetTableAs();
        TableB tableB = null;
        foreach (var tableA in tableAs) {
           tableB.id = tableA.id;
           // ...
           // here I copy/modify records from table A
           // ...
           InsertTableB(tableB);
        } 
    }

    public static List<TableA> GetTableAs()
    {
        using (var ctx = new TableDataContext())
        {
            var entities = from e in ctx.tableAs
                           select e;
            return new List<tableA>(entities);
        }
    }

    public static void InsertTableB(TableB tableB)
    {
        using (var ctx = new TableDataContext())
        {
            ctx.tableBs.InsertOnSubmit(tableB);
            ctx.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

My program will experience "Out of memory" exception after 500k inserts and it is very consistent. And i notice that the memory usage keeps increasing while looping. I even force garbage collection also cannot reclaim any of the memory. Is there anything wrong with my interact with LINQ so that causes the memory hold up and not being released. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not do the whole thing in SQL: rather than moving the data from server to client and back to client keep it all on the server (or move directly from one server to another if TableA and TableB are different SQL Server instances)?

Comment: Have you tried using a .Net memory profiler?

Comment: @Tenerezza seems right. Also: `GetTableAs()` returns a List, which means you have placed all the 1 million records in RAM. Maybe `GetTableAs()` can return just an IQueryable and it will be easier on RAM usage.

Comment: @Ali Ferhat Yes you should as well return just IQueryable as well, but the ToList part is not the biggest problem as he do not run out of memory at once, however with IQueryable he should lower the memory usage by a lot yeah.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost I think you should reconsider the way you write that code, right now it's insane inefficient, example you recreate the context every time, why not just keep ONE context?

Better yet rewrite it into a single SQL statement would save you all hassle.

Recreating the context is pretty heavy CPU wise, and if you just need one connection, as you show with the example above, creating it more then once is waste of resources.

Secondly LINQ to SQL have Change tracking occurring on every object you create, edit, modify, so it knows what objects to deal with. And could possible be the source of your memory problem.

So I would recommend using ObjectTrackingEnabled = false and see what happens.

And lastly you want to peek at Bulk Inserting.

Comment: I could have follow Tenerezza suggestions and the problem would go away. But i would not be able to know what cause the memory leak. With the using keyword construct, all resources should be release once the method call return from the dao api and eligible for GC. But this is not happening.

Comment: @wernergiam: The using only disposes `ctx`. Nothing else. You have no guarantee that `ctx` gets collected. The list with all those entries is a huge load on your memory, but it can only be collected at the end of the scope of main. Also, your foreach in main allocates a heavy load of memory too.

Comment: When the ctx is being dispose and went out of scope what will happened to the ctx object and the object within the cache? When the .net runtime is low on memory and trigger GC shouldn't the out of scope ctx be collected?

Comment: @wernergiam: It could be collected, but you have no guarantee when or even that it will happen. The chance is probably higher if the available memory is low or critical, but still there are chances that the ctx object will not get collected on that run. That's the huge disadvantage of managed applications. If you want to have a better look what is happening, then use a memory profiler like ant. Do you know at which point your application is crashing?

Comment: The biggest problem here is the object state manager, Hence why you should turn it of for every case when you do not need it, it takes up a lot of resources, memory and those things stays even if the context is disposed. The objects them self example keep track of the context to, and since that reference make the context unable to dispose. So overall biggest problem here is not a memory leak, it's bad code and design choices.

Comment: Would the use of ExecuteQuery or ExecuteCommand help to alleviate the problem. Does the entity persisted to db via ExecuteCommand is track by object state manager?

Comment: I have disabled object tracking and disabled defer loading and none of my entities had any associations. I change all the dao api to use ExecuteCommand and ExecuteQuery. I re-run the program using MSTEST and profiler with .net memory profiler. The result show alot of instances of my TableDataContext, TableA and TableB still alive after my program invoke the GC.Collect. This is a serious memory leak as from the code as out of scope references are not garbage collected. Does anyone know how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem when tried to insert over 3000000 rows using linq2sql. OutOfMemoryException was appearing after 700k of inserts. Finally, I just dispose previous DataContext and create new after 100k and even don't turn off tracking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most probably lies not with a memory leak in the .NET CLR, but perhaps the sheer volume of memory that the above LINQ to SQL code requires to execute.

Please refer to this MSDN blog posting first:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/04/10/chat-question-memory-limits-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-processes.aspx

Since I do not have any hardware specifications, I shall assume a memory limit of 2800MB like in the article above.

```
1,000,000 records <= 2800MB
1,000,000 records <= 23,488,102,400 bits
1 record <= 23488.1024 bits
1 record <= 2.8672KB
```

In theory, this means that each record copied into memory from Table A should be no more than 2.8672KB.

However the actual value is usually lower due to other overheads involved with the CLR, and this is reflected in an OutOfMemoryException thrown after 500,000 records deep copied from Table A then inserted into Table B.

Granted there are ways to increase the number of records that can be kept in memory, like other posters have suggested, but the problem will most probably surface again with an increase in the number of records in Table A.

A viable alternative would perhaps be to create a stored procedure in the underlying SQL Server database and execute that instead.